# In solidity, do function signatures take data location into account?

Tags: solidity, evm

ex: if my function in solidity is:

```
function someFunction(uint256 a, bytes calldata _data) external { 
//some stuff 
}
```

would the function signature be the first four bytes of the hash of: `someFunction(uint256,bytes)` or would it be the first four bytes of the hash of: `someFunction(uint256,bytes calldata)`? or even `someFunction(uint256,bytescalldata)` (with no space between bytes and calldata)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the data location is not taken into account. From https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/abi-spec.html#function-selector (my emphasis):

> The first four bytes of the call data for a function call specifies the function to be called. It is the first (left, high-order in big-endian) four bytes of the Keccak-256 (SHA-3) hash of the signature of the function. The signature is defined as the canonical expression of the basic prototype **without data location specifier**, i.e. the function name with the parenthesised list of parameter types. Parameter types are split by a single comma - no spaces are used.